# Ant build failure folder not found

Tags: java, ant

I am getting a ant build failure due to the following line `<property name="classpath" refid="j2ee.classpath"/>` and I am not sure what is configured wrong.

```
 <path id="j2ee.classpath">
   <fileset dir="${env.J2EE_HOME}/lib" includes="j2ee.jar" />
 </path>

 <property name="classpath" refid="j2ee.classpath"/>
```

The error I get is:

```
C:\Users\...\${env.J2EE_HOME}\lib not found.
```

Comment: It seems like the `{env.J2EE_HOME}` did not resolve. Do you have separate environment properties file?

Answer (score 0):

you should load environment variable values before referring to them

```
<property environment="env"/>
<property name="JBOSS_HOME" value="${env.JBOSS_HOME}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check

```
<property name="env.J2EE_HOME" location=".."/>
```

should be correct.